# How to format a border around merged cells vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

So I have a merged cell that looks like below

[image]

Following is my code for putting a border around it:

```
 Dim c As Range

 For Each c In testing  
      If c.MergeCells Then
           c.Interior.ColorIndex = 19
           c.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
           c.Borders.Weight = xlThick
           c.Borders.Color = vbGreen
       End If
   Next
```

This code only creates a border around the top left cell (see picture). How do I ensure that the border is placed around the entire merged cell?

Comment: why the excel-formula tag? when it looks like you want a VBA solution from your title?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the `MergeArea` of the referenced range.

```
Dim c As Range

For Each c In testing  
   If c.MergeCells Then
       With c.MergeArea
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 19
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Borders.Weight = xlThick
            .Borders.Color = vbGreen
       End With 
   End If
 Next
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
With c        'Range of the merged cell
    .BorderAround , Weight:=xlMedium
    .Borders.Color = vbGreen
End With
```

Comment: Hmmm, my answer seems neater and faster than the accepted one

Comment: your solution still doesnt put a border around the whole merged cell

Comment: @sukhvir I wrote this "c        'Range of the merged cell" in my answer, what I meant by that is you have to change the range of merged cell with something else if c has been used, for example `D = Range("B2:D22")`. I wrote it that way since I suspected c is the range of merged cell. And to be more clearly, I always try my code before posting it as an answer. And the code above works fine on my PC.